# A word that describes something that has been given a name

Tags: single-word-requests, names

Is there a word besides *named* that describes something that has been given a proper name?

For example, a guitar is just a guitar, but if I call it, say, Shirley, is there another word that would now describe the guitar?

I'm looking for something specifically that can be used to identify things that have names (like people) but could also include books and movies, or say "Old Glory" for the flag.

Is there such a word?

EDIT: Here's a bit more information:

I'm looking specifically for a noun, a word which describes any object, person, or idea that has a name.

Perhaps an example will help: say you had a hat full of names, movie and book titles, as well as say names of famous characters from tv shows, and maybe even important events in history like "The Great Depression".

If I asked you to reach in and pick one, what could I say to pick besides "choose a name" (and of course, besides "choose a piece of paper"!) that would describe every one of the items in the hat?

EDIT2:
Okay here's some final context for everyone. The reason I posed this question is I am developing a game for windows phone that involves guessing a name, but although "Name" is a simple enough name for the object, it also has additional properties like "category" and "description".

So if I called the object "Name", I need an additional property to reference the actual name of the object. If I used "Name" again I would be accessing it via Name.Name, and that's just silly.

In truth, this isn't a big deal, I ended up using "Name" as the object, and "Title" as the name. This was more a "curiousity" thing, where I wondered if there was a way to accurately name the object, so I could keep "Name" as a property.

Ultimately, my favorite solution is to keep the "Name" as the object and "Moniker" as the name. This feels like the most intuitive way to do it, but I'll probably keep it as it is with "Title". But since that's my favorite that gets the answer, thanks to all who contributed!

Comment: I anthropomorphized my guitar by naming it Shirley

Comment: I *renamed* my guitar.

Comment: wow thanks for all the great comments everyone, this site rocks. I've updated the original post with a little more context. so far I like "term" the best, but wonder if there's something more accurate... thanks again!

Comment: @Josh to the edit: there's a reason that game is referred to as 'the name game' or 'the hat game' rather than anything else...

Comment: What irks me about the clarifying example is: what's wrong with saying *choose a name*? That's the word you're looking for. They're all names. Book names, movie names, character names, names of historical events… This question strikes me as making something more complicated than it needs to be. If you don't like the word "name" simply look in a thesaurus for alternatives to *name*: appellation, moniker, etc.

Comment: thanks for your insight, check my latest edit why just going with "Name" wasn't quite the best option for this situation. thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about ***moniker*** for the noun?

And I'd be inclined to invent ***monikerize*** for the verb.

(I also like ***appelation***, but I don't have the right to up-vote it yet.)

Comment: I'll upvote yours and appellation.

Comment: moniker looks like a winner to me!

Answer (score 24):

[Christen](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/christened) means to name, or to dedicate ceremonially.

Also [dub](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dub) means to honor with a new title (as in "I dub thee Sir Gawain, Knight of the Round Table")

Comment: In light of the OP's clarification of the question, this answer won't do.

Comment: @hstephenstraight, what are you suggesting that I do?

Answer (score 14):

> (adj) **[onymous](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=onymous)** (bearing a name) *"articles in magazines are usually onymous"*

Backformation from *anonymous*? See the OED:

> **[onymous](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/onymous)** Pronunciation: /ˈɒnɪməs/ *adjective*
>   *rare*
>   having a name; named.

Comment: As kids, my sister and I used "onimous" as a jokey mispronunciation of **ominous**: "Ooh, they're playing the *onimous* music - better get out of there!"  I had no idea that it was actually a valid word - albeit spelled a bit differently, of course.

Comment: my kingdom for the plural of this word!

Answer (score 12):

You could say *[yclept](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yclept)*:-

> vb a past participle of clepe
>
> adj having the name of; called

"My guitar, *yclept* Shirley."

The word is marked obsolete, but it's too good to miss, really.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're asking for a noun, whereas several others have provided verbs.

And I think the noun you're after, is **the signified**.

The name, the thing that you're changing, is the signifier. The thing it signifies, is the signified.

So, the thing that is your guitar Shirley, is the signified.  "Your guitar" and "Shirley" are two signifiers for it.

Together, signifier and signified form a sign.

Comment: thank you indeed I am looking for a noun to serve as a placeholder to describe such objects. Signification is not bad, might just fit my needs, thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You might consider **denomination**, which is a name or designation. You can say that the hat contains the *denominations* of various things.

The word **[denomination](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/denomination)** has several meanings, one of which is "a name or designation, especially one for a class of things."

[Etymology Online](http://etymonline.com/?term=denomination) gives this for denomination as the act of denominating:

> denomination (n.) late 14c., "a naming, act of giving a name to," from Old French denominacion "nominating, naming," from Latin denominationem (nominative denominatio) "a calling by anything other than the proper name, metonymy," from denominare "to name," from de- "completely" (see de-) + nominare "to name" (see nominate). Meaning "a class" is from mid-15c. Monetary sense is 1650s; meaning "religious sect" is 1716.

Another word is **[appellation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appellation)**, which is an identifying name or title. B.B. King's $30 guitar received the *appellation* "Lucille" after a woman who was killed in a fire where he was performing. The fire was started when two men fighting over Lucille (the woman) accidentally kicked over a barrel of burning kerosene. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucille_%28guitar%29))

Answer (score 3):

Termed. Dubbed. Called. Titled. Labeled.

Comment: Could you at least write a sentence?! It's often a good idea to embed links in your answer if you're aiming for up-votes :-)

Comment: 2 of those words are included *twice*. Please write proper answers, or leave a brief *Comment* instead of an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that an established word or phrase captures the category you have defined, though "proper name" comes very close, but only for a linguist. In the situation you describe, you would probably need to say something like "This hat contains slips of paper upon which appear the proper names of persons, both real and fictional; titles of well-known movies, books, and other works of art; and names of places and events, such as 'Mount Everest', 'The Eruption of Krakatoa', or 'The Great Depression'. As in the familiar animal-vegetable-mineral game, the aim is for the others here to guess what name you have drawn by taking turns asking yes-no questions of their choice, with an additional turn to a questioner for every 'yes' answer. After each turn, whether it yields a 'yes' or a 'no' answer, the questioner can guess the name. Whoever guesses correctly wins the round, and if no one guesses correctly after 20 'no' answers, the answerer wins the round. The first player to win three rounds wins the game. So, let's start: Pick a name."

But even this answer leaves out other proper names such as Old Glory for the U.S. flag, The Great Communicator for Ronald Reagan, or the G.O.P. for the Republican Party, and, for that matter, the Republican Party itself, which is the proper name of an organization. In short, the phrase "proper name" includes but goes beyond the category you seem to have in mind.

Comment: Or "proper noun."  Although, that is two words.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to say "I left Shirley behind" then no-one in the world would have any idea that you were talking about a guitar. But if B B King were to ask "Where's Lucille?", everyone in the business knows to look for his prized black Gibson.

That is the essence of *having a name*: the mere use of the name (in context) is sufficient to  identify the thing. On the other hand, if you need a word to use in association with the object to indicate that it has a name, then it does not really have a name.

At best you can say "This is my guitar. I call it Shirley."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[style](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/style)*

> to name or call; designate: *to style a man a fool*

Comment: I am looking for a noun, so style won't work, but I do like "Designation" that might do it too, thanks a bunch!

Comment: The terms *identifier* refers to the name of things that are unique, but that term focus on the name rather than the thing. *Identities* refers to the things, but it sounds a bit formal. *Entities* is used in law to refer things that have a legal existence (people and organizations), but not usually to inanimate objects.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your example:

How about appellation?

n : identifying word or words by which someone or something is
         called and classified or distinguished from others

Answer (score 1):

How about ***eponymize***

v. to name something or someone

Comment: Please explain where this word comes from and provide a link to a definition. I have checked in 3 dictionaries (Chambers, ODO, M-W), none of which include it.

Answer (score 1):

Something distinct enough to have a name or other form of unique identifier is an **Entity**.

The verb form of that, to connote that you gave something a name: **Identified** seems like it uses the same root word.

Comment: I really like this, the game is defunct but if I ever revisit it, I think I will use this!

Answer (score 0):

> ... what could I say to pick besides "choose a name" (and of course, besides "choose a piece of paper"!) that would describe every one of the items in the hat?

- "Choose an [**anthroponym**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthroponymy)"

[Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anthroponym): *Noun; a person's name; esp : surname.*

This would also cover the cases when you give people's names to inanimate objects; for instance a guitar or a ship.

- "Choose a **[tag](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=tag)**"

[Definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tag): (12).
*a descriptive word or phrase applied to a person, group, organization, etc., as a label or means of identification; epithet*

Answer (score 0):

Titled.

It means 'given a name'.

He titled his guitar 'Shirley'. His guitar was titled 'Shirley'.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/title